# How to set active profile on Spring Boot while building bootJar?

Tags: spring-boot

how to set profile just for the executable (jar) built by calling bootJar task? Ideally, it would override (or add) a property in application.properties inside the jar or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect he is trying to do exactly what we are. In maven one can do something along these lines:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>openshift</id>
  <properties>
    <activatedProperties>openshift</activatedProperties>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Which can be used to replace `@activatedProperties@` in application.properties to, e.g., openshift. If this is the case, we solved it by modifying build.gradle as follows:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

# whatever you have here

def springProfile = project.hasProperty("profile") ? profile : ""
bootRun {
    systemProperties["spring.profiles.active"] = springProfile
}

processResources {
    with copySpec {
        from "src/main/resources/"
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ["activatedProperties": springProfile])
    }
}
```

and in the application.properties have:

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

However, I would like to note that we consider this a temporary hack. Build scripts should not be modifying files, even if it's limited to resource files. A more correct approach would be to use templates in a separate location and output those to the resources. Or even better (which is what we will do in due time), fix the deployment setup, so it's part of the deployment configuration, as it should be.

Comment: That looks like something that could work. The problem is that it is not a server application and it is a user-facing JAR, so I would like to bundle everything (including configuration) in the jar itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide spring.profiles.active=dev,mysql in your application/bootstrap.properties file of your spring boot application.
Or while running the jar you can provide the active profile as argument,

```
java -jar fatJar.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev,mysql
```